# finding the return value of ExecutionResult - python-graphene

Tags: python, graphene-python

I am new to python (javascript developer

i am following a tutorial, (which is not very good at explaining on why) on using python & graphene

my question is when i print `result` i receive

```
<graphql.execution.base.ExecutionResult object at 0x1071ad410>
```

in javascript, when you console log you can see what is contained in the result variable,

but not sure why i cannot do the same in python, unless im doing it wrong?

from googling, it looks like it returns data, but it would be useful to actually log and see it in the terminal,

```
import graphene
import json

class Query(graphene.ObjectType):
    hello = graphene.String()
    is_admin = graphene.Boolean()

    def resolve_hello(self, info):
        return "world"

    def resolve_is_admin(self, info):
        return True


schema = graphene.Schema(query=Query)

result = schema.execute(
     '''
    {
      isAdmin
    }
     '''
)

print(type(result))

print(result)


i would expect to see the what is the result of the variable `result`
```

Answer (score 1):

Do this to view the data in console:

```
print(result.data)
```